# Why can't my script parse a xml file in a sub directory?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

When I try to parse a xml file in a sub directory I get a `FileNotFoundError`. When I put the file next to the script it can parse it fine. But why?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

path_to_file = os.path.join(script_path, '/test', 'file.xml')

# works
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')

# Throws file not found error
tree = ET.parse(path_to_file)
```

Comment: Remove / from test and try it

Answer (score 2):

Try the easiest possible way of debugging by printing the value of path_to_file.

`os.path.join()` is used so you don't have to specify the (os-specific) path separator character for the path it constructs, which means you don't need to (shouldn't) specify them.

You are over-specifying the path separator on the `test` part - change:

```
path_to_file = os.path.join(script_path, '/test', 'file.xml')
```

to

```
path_to_file = os.path.join(script_path, 'test', 'file.xml')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing `'/test'` without the leading slash.

```
path_to_file = os.path.join(script_path, 'test', 'file.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer myself because although the answers solve the problem, they do not give the correct reason why their code works and mine doesn't.

The significant issue with my code is, that the line

```py
path_to_file = os.path.join(script_path, '/test', 'file.xml')
# Expected value of path_to_file:
# /path/to/script/test/file.xml

# Output of print(path_to_file):
# /test/file.xml
```

contains the **absolute** path `/test` instead of the **relative path** `./test` or as pointed out earlier the better way `test`.
The result is that with `/test`, the resulting path will not contain the contents of `script_path`.

The previous answers might help in cases where you go down one directory, but don't cover cases like

```py
path_to_file = os.path.join(script_path, 'test/subdir', 'file.xml')
```

Where you might find the `/` useful. I think one can trust `os.path.join()` to take care of those platform specific directories. Please let me know if you don't agree with me one this.

Comment: It’s not that ‘the previous answers fail’, it’s that `os.path.join` doesn’t work in the way that you appear to feel is ‘comfortable’. `/test` is an absolute path. The documentation for `os.path.join()` https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.join says “If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component”.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was thinking about adding that, it explains the correct behavior very clearly. I edited my answer to clear up what I meant. `os.path.join()` does work the way I feel comfortable, i just had to use it correctly. It was a plain mistake.